# How do I make it so each user has its own state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a like system similar to Instagram.  The problem's that whenever I like a photo, the `currentUserClicks` state isn't its own state to all users

For example: There exists photos A and B.  A has 10 likes B has 20 likes.

If I click like on photo A, then the like count correctly becomes 11

Right after, if I click like on photo B, then the like count incorrectly becomes 19 instead of 21

The `currentUserClicks` state thinks that photo B should be disliked (decrement the like count by 1 just like Instagram) because `currentUserClicks` becomes >= 1.

How can I make it so that each user has its own `currentUserClicks` value?

```
const [currentUserClicks, setCurrentUserClicks] = useState(null);

const handleLikesBasedOnUserId = (likedPhotoUserId) => {
    if(currentUserClicks >= 1) {
        setCurrentUserClicks(currentUserClicks - 1);
        handleDislike(likedPhotoUserId);
    } else {
        setCurrentUserClicks(currentUserClicks + 1);
        handleLike(likedPhotoUserId);
    }
};
```

Comment: Each image should be a separate instance of the component.

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks for the response. what do you mean by "should be a separate instance of the component"?  Are there any examples that you can point me to please? :)

Comment: What he means is that, when you are looping through your images and displaying them, ideally each image should be it's own component that keeps track of its own state. That way any changes made to that component, don't have any affects on other images.

Comment: You don't need a separate state for each user (the current user is enough), you need a separate state for each photo that can be liked by the current user or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can "individualize" state in a couple basic ways.

1. Push the state *down* to the components it pertains to.

   Here you move the `currentUserClicks` state into a React component that manages its own state and updates, completely independent of any other React component.

   Example:

   ```
   const InstagramPost = (props) => {
     const [liked, setLiked] = useState(false);

     const handleLikesBasedOnUserId = () => {
       if (liked) {
         handleDislike(id); // id from props
       } else {
         handleLike(id);
       }
       setCurrentUserClicks(liked => !liked);
     };

     ...

     return (
       ...
       <button onClick={handleLikesBasedOnUserId}>like</button>
       ...
     );
   };
   ```

   ...

   ```
   {posts.map(post => (
     <InstagramPost key={post.id} ....props.... />
   ))}
   ```
2. Lift the state *up* to a common ancestor component and handle merging state updates.

   Example:

   ```
   const InstagramPost = ({ liked, likeHandler }) => {
     ...
     return (
       ...
       <button onClick={likeHandler}>like</button>
       ...
     );
   };
   ```

   ...

   ```
   const [liked, setLiked] = useState({});

   const handleLikesBasedOnUserId = (id) => {
     if (liked[id]) {
       handleDislike(id);
     } else {
       handleLike(id);
     }
     setCurrentUserClicks(liked => ({
       ...liked,
       [id]: !liked[id], // toggle liked state by id
     }));
   };

   ...

   {posts.map(post => (
     <InstagramPost
       key={post.id}
       liked={liked[post.id]}
       likeHandler={() => handleLikesBasedOnUserId(post.id)}
       ....props....
     />
   ))}
   ```